# wp elementor pro | Change fields in the form

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have an Elementor form whose fields sent by email are saved as leads. I would like to delete some fields after sending the form whose details will not be saved in the leads but will only be sent by email.

I tried several things with no success. There are errors and I can't debug the site:
Would appreciate help.

This is what I tried:

```
    add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', [ $plugin_public, 'remove_if' ], 9, 1 );

    public function remove_if( $record ){
        if( !isset($_POST['post_id']) || !isset($_POST['form_id']) ){
            return false;
        }
        
        $form_id = $record->get_form_settings('form_id');
            
        if($form_id  === "add_extra_fields"){
            $record->set_field( 'field1', '' );
        }

        return $record;
    }
```

also like this:

```
    public function remove_if( $record ){
        if( !isset($_POST['post_id']) || !isset($_POST['form_id']) ){
            return false;
        }
        
        $form_id = $record->get_form_settings('form_id');
            
        if($form_id  === "add_extra_fields"){
            $record->update_field( 'field1', '', '' );
        }

        return $record;
    }
```

please help me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you should `hook` into the correct action and use the appropriate methods provided by Elementor. Try this >>

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function ( $record ) {
    if ( ! $record instanceof \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Form_Record ) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get('fields');
    if ( ! $raw_fields ) {
        return;
    }

    $form_id = $record->get_form_settings('form_id');
    if ( $form_id === 'add_extra_fields' ) {
        $fields_to_remove = ['field1', 'field2']; //you can add your field keys here

        foreach ( $fields_to_remove as $field_key ) {
            if ( isset( $raw_fields[ $field_key ] ) ) {
                unset( $raw_fields[ $field_key ] );
            }
        }
    }

    $record->set( 'fields', $raw_fields );
}, 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you,
The code runs but unfortunately the fields are still saved.

Comment: `if ( isset( $raw_fields[ $field_key ] ) ) {` is not needed before unsetting.  Also `array_diff_key()` comes to mind.